# Not all Cores activated, NR_CPUS limit exceeded

Tags: cpu, lubuntu

Yesterday, I installed Lubuntu 18.04 on my new system:

Mainboard: Asus Rog Strix H370-I

CPU: I7-8700T (6 Cores + Hyperthreading)

Everything works fine, but with `dmesg` I could see this:

```
root@lubuntu:~# dmesg | grep smpboot
[    0.000000] smpboot: 12 Processors exceeds NR_CPUS limit of 8
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 8 CPUs, 0 hotplug CPUs
[    0.028000] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700T CPU @ 2.40GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x9e, stepping: 0xa)
[    0.032868] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[    0.032868] smpboot: Total of 8 processors activated (38400.00 BogoMIPS)
```

Here you can see that the hyperthreading functionality is recognized as additional cores.

The problem is that I can only use 8 of the 12 "cores".

How can I increase the `NR_CPUS` limit from 8 to 12?

`htop` and `top` show 8 cores instead of 12. I don't know if I should install some additional driver or firmware. Or maybe I should wait for new kernels?

Some information given by `lscpu` and `cpuinfo`:

```
root@lubuntu:~# lscpu
Architecture:        i686
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700T CPU @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             800.478
CPU max MHz:         4000.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4800.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            12288K
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ibpb ibrs stibp dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp

root@lubuntu:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 158
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700T CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0x84
cpu MHz         : 800.123
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 6
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug        : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 22
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ibpb ibrs stibp dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2
bogomips        : 4800.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

*[similarly for processors 1 to 7]*

I tested other commands too.

My grub-line looks like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet maxcpus=12 nr_cpus=12 possible_cpus=12 splash"
```

... but it doesn't work -- still only 8 cores.

Other outputs:

```
root@lubuntu:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0-20-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-033) (gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)) #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:15:38 UTC 2018
```

And after edit of grub cmd-line:

```
root@lubuntu:~# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=10cb110b-df14-4a5f-b4de-1791af851f03 ro quiet maxcpus=12 nr_cpus=12 possible_cpus=12 splash vt.handoff=1
```

Today, I realized that I had accidentally installed Lubuntu for **i386** instead of **AMD64**; maybe this could be the cause of my faulty behaviour?
This evening, I will install the right Lubuntu distribution and report.

Comment: The output of `cat /proc/version` and `cat /proc/cmdline` could be relevant in this question.

Answer (score 4):

You can override this with the `nr_cpus` kernel parameter in the bootloader command line.

```
... quiet nr_cpus=12 ...
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html hints that `nr_cpus=` needs `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU`. They might need to check if that is enabled.

Comment: @ilkkachu: For hotplug, sure. But if the number of CPUs is static then they shouldn't need to.

Comment: Okay then, if it doesn't affect that.

Comment: Changed my /etc/default/grub from <GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"> to <GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nr_cpus=12 splash"> followed from this: update-initramfs -u; update-grub; reboot
>>>But it doesn't worked. Only 8 cores insteed of 12...

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

I really have installed i368 Version from Lubuntu. After installing AMD64-Version everything works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is another reason to require `uname -a` output for all questions :)